# Convolution of fractional part with itself

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

Let f(x) be the fractional part of x. I'm asked to find  $F(x)=f*f=\int_{0}^{1}f(x-t)f(t)dt$ explicitly and find its Fourier series.

My first idea was to just integrate $frac(x-t)frac(t)$, getting $\frac{frac(x)}{2}-1/3$.  However, I know that the Fourier coefficients of F must be the square of the coefficients of the fractional part and hence my result is wrong.

Thinking about how (x-t) can be negative, my next attempt was to split the integral (with no success).

So how should I proceed?

Comment: Are you talking about convolutions on $\mathbf R$ or on $\mathbf R/\mathbf Z$?   I assume the latter; in which case your integral should treat the cases $x<t$ and $x>t$ differently.  Or you could work out an $\mathbf R$ convolution of $\chi_{[0,1]}(x)x$ with itself and "wrap" the answer $\bmod 1$.

Comment: Convolution as defined here: http://www.math.hcmuns.edu.vn/~dmduc/lop%20giao%20su%20nuoc%20ngoai/STEIN-SHAKARCHI%20-%20Fourier%20analysis%20-%20An%20introduction%20(book)(Princeton%20University%20Press%202002)%20(326s).pdf (page 44)

Comment: That passage defines convolution of functions of period $2\pi$, that is, of functions on $\mathbb R/2\pi \mathbb Z$.  So what's with your $[0,1]$ integration range?  At any rate, as you originally stated the problem, you want to take into account that $f(x-t) = 1+x-t$ if $0<x<t<1$.

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot Stein uses functions of period 2$\pi$. My f has period 1 so it's R/Z. I'm gonna try again with your suggestion.

Comment: OK I got it, $-x^2/2 +x/2 +1/6$. Thank you kimchi lover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Fourier series of the [sawtooth wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) we have
$$\{x\}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\sin(2\pi k x)}{k}$$
uniformly over any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$. For $x\in(0,1)$

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\{x-t\}\{t\}\,dt = \int_{0}^{x}(x-t)t\,dt +\int_{x}^{1}(1+x-t)t\,dt = \frac{1}{6}+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2} $$
and
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\cos(2\pi k x)}{k^2}.$$